# Update and show mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, select

```
UPDATE myTable SET niceColumn=1 WHERE someVal=1;

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE someVal=1;
```

Is there a way to combine these two queries into one? I mean can I run an update query and it shows the rows it updates. Because here I use "where id=1" filtering twice, I don't want this. Also I think if someVal changes before select query I will have troubles about what I get (ex: update updates it and after that someVal becomes 0 because of other script).

Comment: Any reason why you don't want this?

Comment: show the rows it updates is different than selecting rows with some value...

Comment: I don't want to do same job twice, suppose I have a big table.

Comment: deniz, it's not the same job twice. You update - 1 job. You look for data - another job. If you have proper indexes on someVal, it should be very easy on the db.

Comment: don't try to fix a problem that does not exist. 2 queries is fine

Comment: but just before I made select query if one of someVal values(which was 1) changes, I will lose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the two queries in a transaction with the desired [`ISOLATION LEVEL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dynindex-isolevel.html) so that no other threads can't affect the locked rows between the update and the select.

Answer (score 0):

If in your real code the conditional part (where and so on) is too long to repeat, just put it in a variable that you use in both queries.

Unless you encounter a different problem, you shouldn't need these two combined.

Comment: oh, I actually never tried but totally thought you could =/ my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, even what you have done will not show the rows it updated, because meanwhile (after the update) some process may add/change rows.

And this will show all the records, including the ones updated yesterday :)

If I want to see exactly which rows were changed, I would go with temp table. First select into a temp table all the row IDs to be updated. Then perform the update based on the raw IDs in the temp table, and then return the temp table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE to_be_updated
SELECT id
FROM myTable
WHERE someVal = 1;

UPDATE myTable
SET niceColumn = 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM to_be_updated);

SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM to_be_updated)
```